# BizTalk server 2006 R2 not using recently "GAC"ced dll

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I have a DLL which is `GAC`'ced (`c:\windows\assembly`) which is being used by my `Biztalk` Application, for some requirement, I changed a function in that DLL and:

1. I uninstalled the old DLL which was in `GAC` (version 1.0.0.0)
2. I `GAC`'ced the newly built DLL into `GAC` (version 1.0.0.0)
3. I also restarted the `BizTalk` Host Instances.

But still the output *seems* to be from the old DLL's function. I am not getting the problem, why still I am getting the old output.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

Some tips that might be helpful:

(1) If you have multiple BizTalk servers in your group, be sure to update all of the servers!
Depending on your host instance configuration, your instance may run on any server the host instance is active on.

(2) Make sure you restart the correct biztalk host instance. This is often overlooked. Don't forget about the BizTalk Isolated Host! Perform a recycle of the specific IIS application pool if necessary. If you are unsure, perform an iisreset.exe

(3) To update a DLL in BizTalk it is often necessary to update it in the BizTalk database as well. For some changes it may work just updating the DLL in the GAC, but often I find that this is not enough (especially with orchestrations).

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing here is correct.  You should see the new DLL taking over.  A couple things to check:

1. Did you recycle the correct host instances?
2. Did you recylce the host instances on all servers?
3. Did you veriiify the Create date on the GAC'd DLL to ensure the new one was installed?

Another issue might be based on what you changed in the Application.  You can only Gac/Restart under particular circumstances.  See this [When can you just re-gac and re-start](http://www.jonflanders.com/?p=1361) on Jon Flander's blog for reference.

Comment: Afraid the link to Jon Flanders blog is invalid  :-(

Comment: @SteveC Updated the link.  Although the key piece, the image is broken (still pointing at old location)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be really sure that the correct assembly that has been GAC:ed, click "Run" and type "%systemroot%\assembly\gac" for .Net 1.1 or "%systemroot%\assembly\gac_msil" for > 2.0.

There you have the physical files for each version number to be checked (or overwrited).

It might help us support you if you let us know what part of BizTalk you are using the assembly, pipeline, functoid, schema etc.

Answer (score -1):

Is that DLL used under a BizTalk process (BTSNTSvc.exe) or by an Isolated Host Instance?

If this DLL is used in a Receive Location which Receive Handler (Host) is Isolated, for example a SOAP Receive Location, you have to restart the Application pool from IIS and not the Host Instance.